# Earth enslaved by aliens. Last sentence of the short story gives added grimness to it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I read this short story about 25 years ago. It may be older than that.

It is a grim story with examples of the harshness of the alien rule. The thing that made it memorable for me was the last sentence which added one more example of the horror. It was a surprise and packed a punch.

A few hints are given in the story: A man faints from hunger but gets right up and continues to work; the narrator mentions how he was a doctor 50 years ago when the aliens arrived.

His last thought is that he hopes he has time for the alien bureaucrat to certify his death warrant.

Comment: Stick around. We had this one recently.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @AndresF. I've checked both question and answer here, and I don't see any acceptance.

Comment: Reopened because it does not meet the criteria for closing as duplicate.

Comment: The confusion may be due to my slightly clumsy way of indicating that the earlier Q&A I linked was accepted in the comments.

Comment: @DavidW the other question was "accepted" in the comments, which is the spirit if not the letter of the law. I think we should be flexible, consider it accepted, and close this one. We are not bureaucratic aliens ;)

Comment: @AndresF. Problem is, Taxdodger hasn't accepted this one.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots oh, I see. So we can only close as dupe when both questions have accepted answers? Unwieldy, though I can see why. Fair enough. (Alternatively, we could close more aggressively and only reopen if the second asker claims "hey, that's not the answer!").

Comment: @AndresF.: [story-identification questions have specific rules](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) because they are a bit subjective. It may or may not be the best solution, but it's the best we've found so far.

Comment: @Taxdodger could you see if the posted answer is the one you were looking for? If so, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify this science fiction short story about alien conquest of Earth, man seeking permission to die](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143448/identify-this-science-fiction-short-story-about-alien-conquest-of-earth-man-see)

Answer (score 18):

OK, not actually a recent question, but [one I ran into recently](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143448/identify-this-science-fiction-short-story-about-alien-conquest-of-earth-man-see).

"[The Certificate](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56761)" by Avram Davidson (1959), described [here](https://klshorts.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/the-certificate-1959-by-avram-davidson/) as:

> Fifty years after the arrival of aliens, one of the small percentage of men left alive enters the alien bureaucracy dreaming of a new overcoat -- or better yet, escape.

The last line is:

> He had achieved his escape after all — but only if he got there before ten o'clock

It can be read [here](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v016n03_1959-03_PDF/page/n67/mode/2up).

Comment: Confirmed via comment in the linked question.

Comment: shouldn't we close as dupe instead of writing an answer?

Comment: @AndresF. We can't close as a dupe until both are accepted.

Comment: TBF 2016 is recent

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it was accepted in comments by the asker; he/she just doesn't know or care to mark accepted. Do you see the irony in this question of following protocol over the spirit of the law? (Bureocratic aliens!)